# A formula similar to $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\mu\left[a,b \right]$ for $f^p$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be an absolutely continuous measure with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ , and $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R^+}$ its Radon-Nikodym derivative  . We can write $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ in term of $\mu$ by the formula 
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\mu\left[a,b \right].$$
Now for some $p\geq 0$, can we write $\int_a^b(f(x))^pdx$ in term of the measure $\mu$ only?

I tried 
$$\int_a^b(f(x))^pdx=\int_a^b(f(x))^{p-1}f(x)dx=\int_a^b(f(x))^{p-1}d\mu(x).$$
But I still have the term $f$ in the formula, I want to write this only in term of $\mu$. I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: I don't think (this is not rigorous) this will be possible, because the Radon Nikodym derivative depends upon the measure $\mu$ and the Lebesgue measure. If we take e.g. $2 \lambda$ (let me denote Lebesgue measure by $\lambda$) instead of $\lambda$, then we get $g := f/2$ instead of $f$ as the Radon Nikodym derivative (w.r.t. $2\lambda$)and hence $\int g^p d(2\lambda) = 2^{1-p} \cdot \int f^p d\lambda$. This shows that the question you are asking is dependent on the "second measure". As there is no real reason for prefering $\lambda$ to $2\lambda$, this indicates it is not possible.